# Is there wavefunction interference between alternate reaction pathways?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, quantum-chemistry, reaction-control

I'll give a specific example to clarify my question. If we look at the approach of chloromethylenecarbene's electron pair to cis-2-butene in the reaction of creating 1-chloro-2,3-dimethylcyclopropane, there's a symmetry in the choice of where the nucleophilic attack can happen.

These two alternatives can be represented by wavefunctions and so I would expect there to be an interference effect between them that would make the reaction different than if one of the spots was somehow unavailable for reaction (perhaps by the existence of some electron donating/withdrawing groups or other hindering groups attached on the periphery of the butene's double bonds).

Has reaction pathway alternatives interference been observed?

Comment: I'm not getting your point.

Comment: I've already asked the question as best as I think I could.